# p4 reconcile incorrectly marks an existing file as add

Tags: addition, edit, perforce, workspace, changelist

For certain files, `p4 reconcile //...` will incorrectly mark an edited file as `add`.

1. `p4 edit foo.pm`. File foo.pm is marked correctly as 'edit'.
2. `p4 reconcile //...`.  File foo.pm is now marked *incorrectly* as 'add'.

I can't find any difference between these files and others in my workspace. They are text/code files. Other files with the same extension in the same directory don't have this issue.

I have tried (1)  deleting the files, (2) p4 sync -f the entire directory, and even (3) creating a new workspace.

Version: `Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2014.1/807760 (2014/03/18)`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bug, possibly an old/fixed one.  What version of the server are you on?  ("p4 info")

Comment: for example:  #625432 (Bug #65155) **
     In some cases unpromoted task stream files were not being seen
     by certain commands.  This problem could also manifest itself 
     by causing an unnecessary sync replace operation when switching
     between stream clients.  The commands affected are sync, diff,
     edit, reconcile, fstat, files, filelog, annotate and delete.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry forgot to include the version. Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2014.1/807760 (2014/03/18)